# Flash SMS in Windows Mobile

Tags: c#, .net, c++, windows-mobile, sms

How can i write code for send Flash SMS (Sms Class 0) in Windows Mobile? please guide me with .NET or C++ code also .Net is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`PROVIDER_SPECIFIC_MESSAGE_CLASS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms862960.aspx) enumeration's `PS_MESSAGE_CLASS0` value provided in a call to [`SmsSendMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa455068.aspx) (the `pbProviderSpecificData` parameter).

This code is a bit lower level than Compact Framework's APIs, thus gives you some more control over the message you want to send. You have to marshall it from native DLL. [Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446545.aspx) an example of using it in Compact Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Use this enumeration with the TEXT_PROVIDER_SPECIFIC_DATA and NOTIFICATION_PROVIDER_SPECIFIC_DATA structures when calling SmsSendMessage and SmsReadMessage after having called SmsOpen with the message class. Refer to GSM specification 03.40 "Digital Cellular telecommunications system (Phase 2+); Technical realization of the Short Message Service (SMS)" for more details.

enum PROVIDER_SPECIFIC_MESSAGE_CLASS {
PS_MESSAGE_CLASS0 = 0,
PS_MESSAGE_CLASS1,
PS_MESSAGE_CLASS2,
PS_MESSAGE_CLASS3,
PS_MESSAGE_CLASSUNSPECIFIED,
};